# How to hide and show the keyboard on an iPhone using Phonegap and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

In my Phonegap application, I have one screen where if the user taps or clicks outside of the textarea, the keyboard should hide. I used the `.blur(` function, but by doing that the screen goes up and the user can't see the application bar on the top (the screen itself doesn't move though).

Answer (score 2):

After calling blur, try `window.scrollTo(0,0)`.

If I recall correctly, you might have to wrap it in a 0ms setTimeout

```
$('#someInput').blur();
setTimeout(function(){
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}, 0);
```