# Preventing iOS Keyboard from scrolling page in cordova 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am using Cordova 3.5 and jQuery mobile to build an iOS app. I have disabled scrolling in most of the app; however, when I select an input field, the iOS keyboard opens and scrolls the page up.  I do not want this functionality. Since the input is high enough that the keyboard would not cover it up, I want the page to remain still while the keyboard covers up the bottom part of the page.

This question is similar to a number of others like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952782/preventing-an-input-element-from-scrolling-the-screen-on-iphone), and is the opposite of the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237918/cordova-phonegap-3-1-keyboard-still-overlays-focused-form-fields-ios-7).

However, none of the posted answers worked for me, so I will post my solution here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add [this plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard) with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git
```

in the command line.

Add the following line anywhere it the javascript to disable scrolling from the keyboard.

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

In my use case, I added a `deviceready` event listener to evaluate this line, disabling the automatic keyboard scrolling everywhere in the app.

That's it!

Comment: This plugin disables all scrolling in my app - is there any other setup that I need to do to only disable the auto-scrolling and not all scrolling?

Comment: You might want to explore re-enabling scrolling with cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false); when the keyboard is hidden. You can tell when the keyboard is hidden with the native.keyboardhide event. The README at https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard has some information about how the plugin works that might be useful. It's been a while since I've worked with this though, so if you're having trouble you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: Cannot find name 'cordova'.

      L38:  ngAfterViewInit() {
      L39:    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

Comment: This function has been removed on latest version of the plguin.
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/42

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, and saying this as a developer who avoids 3rd party plugins as much as possible, I've found that virtual keyboard issues in Cordova are best solved with a plugin.

The Cordova plugin directory has several `keyboard` plugins
(http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=keyboard)

I recommend the following plugin:
https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard

Which provides the following command to disable scrolling when the virtual keyboard is open.

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScrollingInShrinkView(true);
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I found a really simple answer and none of the others worked.

In your css do:

```
html {
  touch-action: none;
}
body {
  touch-action: all;
}
```

Comment: This works with a quasar cordova app. The plugin solutions did NOT work.