# Scroll Screen when keyboard is open Cordova Ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I have created a Cordova ionic application which has an editor. I have an index.html page. I have one editor.html page. To navigate to the editor page, I have used:

window.open('editor.html')

I have added cordova.js at the top in editor.html. 
I want to scroll the screen when user enter any TEXT on the editor as it is hiding the data when I'm typing. I have added keyboard plugin. What can I do to make this work?

**meta tags which I have used in index.html:**

```
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
       <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
       <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

[image]

Comment: can you add the meta tags in your index.html to the question?

Comment: please check, I have edited the answer

Comment: Try replacing your `viewport` meta tag with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">`

Comment: I tried adding but it is not working...

Comment: Refer https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/scroll-to-the-focused-item-input-when-the-keyboard-is-up/422/2 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865973/preventing-ios-keyboard-from-scrolling-page-in-cordova-3-5

Comment: I already tried adding that too but still no luck :(