# IOS7 web application focusing an input disable the scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, ios7

I'm developping a mobile web application and this bug appears when I want to focus an input by taping on it. If the keyboard goes upper than the input, I cannot scroll down my screen to see the input, and if I type something, nothing appears in the field.

I have to go to another field by using the arrows on the keyboard, and then go back.

Anyone knows a way to fix that?

I'm using the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap, Spinejs, safari, ios7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution in this stackoverflow post, it's a safari bug on ios7: [Issue with iOS 7 Mobile Safari Scroll Events on Keyboard Up and Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172922/issue-with-ios-7-mobile-safari-scroll-events-on-keyboard-up-and-down?answertab=active#tab-top)